# How to execute Table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following function which returns Table .

```
create Function FN(@Str varchar(30))
  returns
  @Names table(name varchar(25))
  as 
  begin 

      while (charindex(',', @str) > 0)
      begin
      insert into @Names values(substring(@str, 1, charindex(',', @str) - 1))
     set  @str = substring(@str, charindex(',', @str) + 1, 100)  
      end
      insert into @Names values(@str)  

      return
  end
```

Could any one please explain me how to run this function.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

A [TVF (table-valued function)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) is supposed to be SELECTed FROM. Try this:

```
select * from FN('myFunc')
```

Comment: Note that depending upon the server/setup you may need to identify the schema e.g. select * from dbo.FN('myFunc')

Answer (score 70):

You can execute it just as you select a table using `SELECT` clause. In addition you can provide parameters within parentheses.

Try with below syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM yourFunctionName(parameter1, parameter2)
```