# How to pass a @param value in SELECT FUNCTION that returns TABLE, in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, function, select

I want to pass a param value into a function in sql server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc(@param varchar(30))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(
     SELECT @param FROM MyTable
)
GO;
```

Can somebody help me?
I need do it using a function.
Thanks

I have considered the solution procedure and exec, however need to be a function not a procedure, because then I'd like to do joins between the results of the function and other tables.
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyFunction ('column1, column2, column3, columnN, etc') MyTable INNER JOIN ON (....);
```

A procedure does not work for me Joins other tables.

In addition,,,, not always be three values to select, so I do not set the table structure.

```
Sometimes it will be:
id column1  column2
1  value1   value1.2
2  value2   value2.2

Sometimes it will be:
id column1  column2   column3
1  value1   value1.2  value1.3
2  value2   value2.2  value2.3
```

Comment: Aside from the apparent uselessness of this function the only thing wrong syntactically is you need to name the column in your select statement. Why does this have to be a function? The way this is written it will return the same value that you pass in for every row in the table. I have a feeling that isn't what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute Table valued function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953417/how-to-execute-table-valued-function)

Comment: are you trying to pass the column name as a parameter to your function ??

Comment: You can't parameterize column names (or table names, for that matter).
So the only way to do such a thing is using dynamicSql, though I'm not sure it can be done with a udf.

Comment: Wow I wasn't even thinking the OP was wanting to pass in the column name to be selected. Reading this now I think that seems as close to a guess as can be made.

Comment: @SeanLange Actually, I thought that was rather obvious... perhaps the reason you didn't think about that is that you are looking from the eyes of someone that knows it's impossible so you wouldn't even let your mind go there...

Comment: @ZoharPeled that is probably likely although we have all seen the attempt at doing this kind of thing so many times. Oh well...back to my actual work. :)

Comment: @TabAlleman the solution in How to execute Table valued function does not work for me.. for this reason i have create a new post.

Comment: That's because your question isn't really how to pass a parameter.  It's how to do dynamic SQL in a function.  I don't see your new post, btw

Comment: My question is as I formulated, do not need a procedure, understand, this solution does not work for me, I need to be in a function, Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can't parameterize column names (or table names, for that matter), So the only way to do such a thing is using dynamic Sql.
This also means that you can't use a user defined table function to do this, since that requires a hard-coded well-defined table to be returned.

You can, however, use a stored procedure to do such a thing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_FROM_TABLE
(
    @ColumnName sysname,
    @TableName sysname
)
AS

DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT '+ @ColumnName +' FROM '+ @TableName

EXEC(@Sql)

GO
```

Note: This kind of procedure should **NEVER** be exposed outside of your database. the reason for that is that it's a **HUGH** risk for [Sql injection attacks.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Should you decide to create a procedure like this, you **MUST** verify the inputs inside the stored procedure itself. Something like this should get you started:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_FROM_TABLE
(
    @ColumnName sysname,
    @TableName sysname
)
AS

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName 
    AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT '+ @ColumnName +' FROM '+ @TableName
    EXEC(@Sql)

END

GO
```

This way, you can be sure that the column name and table name passed to the procedure actually exists in your database.

Comment: I have considered the solution procedure and exec, however need to be a function not a procedure, because then I'd like to do joins between the results of the function and other tables.
Something like:

`SELECT * FROM MyFunction ('field1, field2, field3') MyTable INNER JOIN ON (....);`

Comment: Well, you can create a table variable and use insert...exec to populate it from a stored procedure, and then use it to join other tables in another statement.