# Use a table-valued function in a SELECT column list?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953417/how-to-execute-table-valued-function) that a table-valued function is designed to appear in the `FROM` clause, but is there a way to include it in the column list, viz:

```
SELECT
 x.a,
 x.b,
 FN(x.c),
 x.d
FROM x;
```

... where the expected output might be something like the following?

```
|x.a|x.b|fn_col_1|fn_col_2|fn_col_3|x.d|
```

Comment: Table valued functions return tables, as the name implies.  You should probably try to find another way to do this.

Comment: I guess I'm after a row-valued function. I have a function which, depending on a supplied parameter, can return about 8 different values. The issue is that to calculate any 1 of the values requires calculating all of them, and that's a lot of work - so when I want a query like above, and I want to return each of those 8 values, the same (or very similar) work gets executed 8 times per row of results. Would be nice to call the function once and return the 8 values together for 1/8th of the processing. I'll look into joining TVF with the other table.

Comment: No you can't. Try to find a different solution.

Comment: Just join the TVF.

Comment: As mentioned; create a TVF that only returns one row and multiple fields. `CROSS APPLY` to it (or `INNER JOIN`) and include the columns in the select list. If this is a slow TVF you're going to get performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `cross apply` a TVF to a regular table e.g.

```
SELECT
 x.a
 , x.b
 , x.d
 , y.*
FROM x
cross apply FN(x.c) y;
```